# Save SVG as PNG (or other) with javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, reactjs

I want to save a generated SVG (by a javascript graphing library using d3) as a PNG or other image format.

I tried:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

This does not render my SVG to a canvas. The example works but not with my SVG as it does not contain the `<foreignObject>` directive.

Is there an other way to save the image that does not involve the server side?

Technical details:

- Project is in ReactJS
- I use the 'Recharts' library for charting although I consider switching to 'Victory'.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like that:

[Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf/3514404#3514404)

They suggest to create a data url:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Then add an img element with the data url to the DOM

```
document.write('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
```

or just assign it to the window.location

```
window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```